# Cómo trabajar con Client Storage desde un Panel SD

Tags: genexus

Estoy trabajando sobre un objeto Panel SD.

Cuando escribo un ClientStorage.Set ('nombreKey', valor)
si lo escribo directo de un Evento de Usuario (por el ej: dentro de un ControlValueChanged), ó un clientstorage.Get('nombreKey')  dentro del evento ClientStart. En esos casos funciona bien, sin errores.

Pero cuando agrupo los ClientStorage.Set y/o clientstorage.Get dentro de Procedures, al compilar (F5)
me tira el error:

========== Specification started ==========

Specifying prc_GrabaDatosToCS ...

**error spc0200: External Object GeneXus\Client\ClientStorage does not implement method 'set(' for C# Web environment. **(Procedure 'prc_GrabaDatosToCS', Details)****

Specifying VitaD_PNPrincipal_Level_Detail ...

Generating Resources...Success

Failed: Specification

Esto que intento hacer de agrupar los SET en un procedure y los GET en otro procedure para ser llamados desde los eventos del panel, no puedo hacerlo entonces?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: No funcionan en procedures. Solo es posible utilizarlos desde eventos de un SDPanel.

Comment: Puede funcionar si el procedure esta marcado como conectividad offline

Comment: ¿Por qué? ¿Cómo y donde se cambia?

Comment: Es una propiedad del objeto Gx...  por defecto lo vas a ver en inherit.
Debes setearlo en offline...  eso hará que se genere solo para ejecutarse en el sd y no en el server...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El client storage SD funciona en el cliente, no en el server, precisamente porque estas queriendo guardar info en el storage del cliente (device).

Si llamas a un set o get dentro de un procedure online corre en el server-side y entonces no te va a funcionar, tal como indica el error.

Saludos!